# unable to perform list operation on dict keys, and values:

Tags: python-3.7

I tried the below code to perform list operation on a dictionary k, v like given below:
for k, v in dictionary:
print(f"{k}, {v}")
but getting error as giving below:
can't perform loop on dictionary directly.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to iterate over its `.items`, but I don't recognise that error message at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [items()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_items.asp) method it returns the dictionary as 2d array

```py
for key , val in dicObj.items():
    print(f"{key}, {val}")
```

or

```py
for key in dicObj.keys():
    print(f"{key}, {dicObj[key]}")
```